# Getting Active CDocument's File Icon

Tags: c++, mfc, mdi

I have an MFC MDI application in which I need to use the active `CDocument`'s file icon. I know that the icon ID is set when specifying the document template (it is the first parameter in the `CMultiDocTemplate` constructor), but having searched the documentation (and header files) for `CDocument`, `CMultiDocTemplate` and `CDocTemplate` I can find no way to retrieve the icon's ID. Unfortunately all are defined in afxwin.h, so the source code isn't accessible. `CDocTemplate` does have a protected member variable, `m_nIDResource` which I'm guessing is set to the resource ID passed to the constructor, but there is no accessor for this variable.

I could write a thin wrapper class for `CMultiDocTemplate` and provide an accessor for the icon ID, but I thought I'd ask first if anyone has found a way to get the file icon?

Comment: It's a quite good approach, and not much work, so I would say go ahead. Another solution could be get the current MDI child and call `GetIcon()`.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a wrapper class for `CMultiDocTemplate` and adding an accessor for `m_nIDResource` worked well.

As `CMDIChildWnd` uses the active document's file icon for its frames, there must be some in-built way of getting the icon, but oh well, this is a pretty simple work-around.

Comment: Is it possible for you to maybe use `CMDIChildWndEx` instead? It has `GetFrameIcon`. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmdichildwndex-class?view=vs-2019#getframeicon. By default this method returns the window icon. Override `GetFrameIcon` in a `CMDIChildWndEx`-derived class to customize this behavior.

Comment: Unfortunately not in this case, as I'm actually using this from within my own custom drawn child frame, but yes, in a generic situation, I think that would also work.